# When refreshing the page, the default active tab shows quickly before the last active tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tabs with the "active" class set on the second tab. When refreshing the page, no matter what tab I'm on, that default active tab always shows for a second before the last visited tab is displayed. How do I stop this?

Here is my code: 
**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li><a class="cta2" href="home.html#contact">Get an offer</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#kids" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kids</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#documentary" aria-controls="documentary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Documentary</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#lifestyle" aria-controls="lifestyle" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lifestyle</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#news" aria-controls="news" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#fashion" aria-controls="fashion" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fashion</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#sports" aria-controls="sports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sports</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#music" aria-controls="music" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Music</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#adult" aria-controls="adult" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Adult</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() { 
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {  
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
});

var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
    $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
}    
});
```

Comment: is your Jquery code run? My best shot is; your jquery code is not in the document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code will be executed once the document is ready, which is a non-zero amount of time after the page is visible to the user.

A simple hack would be to add `display: none;` to the tab list, then show the list after you've set the visible tab using the data in `localStorage`.

A better way to do this would be to save the current tab in a session variable and set the `active` class to the corresponding tab when you generate the HTML.

---

**Adding `display: none;` to the list:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="display: none;">
  <li><a class="cta2" href="home.html#contact">Get an offer</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#kids" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kids</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#documentary" aria-controls="documentary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Documentary</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#lifestyle" aria-controls="lifestyle" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lifestyle</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#news" aria-controls="news" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#fashion" aria-controls="fashion" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fashion</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#sports" aria-controls="sports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sports</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#music" aria-controls="music" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Music</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#adult" aria-controls="adult" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Adult</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Showing the list after you've set the tab:**

```
$(function() { 
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {  
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
    $('.nav-tabs').show();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer is way above my head.

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo I've updated my answer with code changes. Note the `style="..."` in the `ul` and the `$('.nav-tabs').show()` in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but didn't work, the default active tab still shows before the tab that was last shown before the refresh